# What is the advantage having object/arrays rather than fields in documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

As a example , what is the advantage of having object for store latitude and longitude rather than having 2 separate fields for store latitude and longitude? Is there any advantage on size?

Answer (score 2):

actually if I had to recommend anything I would recommend keeping any geographical information in geojson format

more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON

for example to keep info about specific point you have

```
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [0, 0] }
```

The advantage for example comes whenever you have to export your data from one source to another, and both will probably be able to consume it without any changes, what in theory may happen when you use your own format.
I once kept geojson in my db and later on consumed it in my app which was using OpenStreetMap.